How to sum values in a column based on string detection in another column and store it into a separate dataframe in R
I have a dataset of projects that I am trying to analyse based on themes and funding received.
I have a column "theme" with several keywords listed. I have all unique keywords possible in a list, and I am trying to sum, for each keyword, the total funding received, and store it in a dataframe.
As an example, my initial dataset would be:
df



Projects
Themes
Funding




Project 1
Agriculture, Water, Food
50 000


Project 2
Agriculture, Digital
100 000


Project 3
Agriculture, Food
50 000


Project 4
Urban planning, Food, Water, Digital
200 000


Project 5
Agriculture
30 000



My list of keywords "keywords_list" is a list of characters containing "Agriculture", "Water", "Food", "Digital", "Urban planning".
The result I would like is:
themes_analysis



Keywords
Count
Funding




Agriculture
4
230 000


Water
2
250 000


Food
3
300 000


Digital
2
300 000


Urban planning
1
200 000



I already managed to have the first two columns thanks to the functions
themes_string_sep <- strsplit(df$Themes, split = ",")
keywords_list <- unlist(themes_string_sep)
themes_analysis <- as.data.frame(table(keywords_list))
keywords_list <- unique(keywords_list)

However I am having trouble finding how to sum the funding by searching for the keywords.
I tried different variations of ifelse function:
1.
themes_analysis$Funding <- 0
themes_analysis$Funding <- ifelse((str_detect(df$Themes, themes_analysis$Keywords))== TRUE, sum(themes_analysis$sum_funding, df$Funding), themes_analysis$Funding)

which returns "Error in str_detect(): ! Can't recycle string (size 312) to match pattern (size 93). Backtrace:  1. base::ifelse(...)  2. stringr::str_detect(df$Themes, themes_analysis$Funding)"
2)
themes_analysis$Funding <- 0
themes_analysis$Funding <- ifelse((df$Themes %in% themes_analysis$Keywords))== TRUE, sum(themes_analysis$Funding, df$Funding), themes_analysis$Funding)

which returns the error "Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Funding, value = c(318793741, 318793741,  :  the replacement table has 312 lines, the replaced table has 93 lines"

I also tried:
themes_analysis$Funding <- sum(df[which(df$Themes %in% themes_analysis$Keywords), 3])
which gives me the same incorrect number for every row, which is not what I want.

I cannot find any answer online so far.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Using dplyr and tidyr you can use
dd |> 
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(Themes, ", ") |>
  dplyr::summarize(count= dplyr::n(), funding=sum(Funding), .by=Themes)

To get
          Themes count funding
1    Agriculture     4  230000
2          Water     2  250000
3           Food     3  300000
4        Digital     2  300000
5 Urban planning     1  200000

Don't worry about searching the columns yourself, just split the multivalued cells into a tidy format by creating separate rows for each value.
Tested with
dd <- data.frame(Projects = c("Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3", "Project 4", "Project 5"), 
                 Themes = c("Agriculture, Water, Food", "Agriculture, Digital", "Agriculture, Food", "Urban planning, Food, Water, Digital", "Agriculture"), 
                 Funding = c(50000L, 100000L, 50000L, 200000L, 30000L))



Here is another base R approach
a <- strsplit(df$Themes,", ")
count <- c(table(b <- unlist(a)))
funding <- tapply(rep(df$Funding, lengths(a)), b, sum)
data.frame(Themes = names(count), count, funding)

                       Themes count funding
Agriculture       Agriculture     4  230000
Digital               Digital     2  300000
Food                     Food     3  300000
Urban planning Urban planning     1  200000
Water                   Water     2  250000

you could also use aggregate:
df |>
   with(setNames(strsplit(Themes, ", "), Funding))|>
   stack() |>
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)|>
   aggregate(ind~., \(x)c(count = length(x), funding = sum(x)))

          values ind.count ind.funding
1    Agriculture         4      230000
2        Digital         2      300000
3           Food         3      300000
4 Urban planning         1      200000
5          Water         2      250000


If you want to do this in base R, you can add the following code to create your extra column:
themes_analysis$Funding <- sapply(keywords_list, function(x){  
  sum(df1$Funding[grepl(x, df1$Themes)])
})

Incidentally, I have changed your data frame name to df1 (df is a function).  Also, sapply is fine in a simple interactive situation, but is generally frowned upon for production code.

thank you for your answer and for this additional piece of knowledge, I didn't know it was frowned upon.
